# Header file wont work -undefined reference to `method'

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Header File doesn't seem to work properly.
I'm new to C and don't really know what i'm doing

```
error - findvals.c:(.text+0x561): undefined reference to `approxEqual'
```

findvals.c

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "utils.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  //printf("GRR ENTAR SOMETHANG");
  //char word[64];
  //scanf("%s", word);
  int count = 0;
  int ret;
  double x;
  double y;
  int i = 0;
  int c = 0;
  char *refStr, *tolStr;
  double refDub;
  double tolDub;
  int noArgs = 0;
  //double temp;
  //scanf("%lf" , &temp);
  //printf("DUBBB %lf" , temp);

  refStr = tolStr = NULL;

  //Add code to read arguments, in ANY order i.e. -r can come before or after -t  
  int processCount = 0;
  for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-r"))
    {
      tolStr = argv[i+1];
      i++;
      //printf("\nIM HERE r");
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-t"))
    {
      refStr = argv[i+1];
      i++;
      //printf("\nIM HERE t");
    }
  }

  refDub = atof(refStr);
  tolDub = atof(tolStr);

  //printf("\nrefDub = %f", refDub);
  //printf("\ntolDub = %f", tolDub);



  //Check if arguments were passed in correctly.
  if (argc != 5 || refStr == NULL || tolStr == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -r ref -t tol\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  //Add code to note start time and date and then print it. 
  //Right now printing just a default string
  struct tm *local;
  time_t start, end;
  time(&start); // read and record clock
  local = localtime(&start);
  printf("\n# Start time and date: %s", asctime(local));
  //char * tnd="Wed 15 Oct 2014 19:18:13 IST";
  //printf("# Start time and date: %s", tnd );
  // Add rest of the functionality. 

  //READ
  int rows; // Sixe x axis of the array
  int cols; // Sixe y axis o the array
  scanf("%d" , &rows);
  scanf("%d" , &cols);
  double opArray[rows][cols]; // Array for operations

  for(i = 0 ; i < rows; i++)
  {
    for(c = 0 ; c < cols; c++)
    {
      scanf("%lf" , &opArray[i][c]);
    }
  }

  //read in the matrix

  double **mat = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*rows);
  int j=0;
  for(i=0; i<rows; i++) 
  /* Allocate array, store pointer  */
  mat[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*cols); 

  for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
    {
      scanf("%lf",&mat[i][j]);
    }
  }



  // The following print statement should be a part of a loop
  // Uncomment it tailor it to your code but ONLY the part that 
  // comes after:  \n",

  // fprintf(stdout, "r=%d, c=%d: %.6f\n", r, c, rows[r][c]);
  for(i= 0; i < rows ; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0 ; j <cols ; j++)
    {
      ret = approxEqual(mat[i][j],refDub,tolDub);
      if (ret == 1)
      {
        fprintf(stdout, "r=%d, c=%d: %.6f\n", i, j, mat[i][j]);
        count++;
      }
    }
  }




  // output the final count of matches. Again, you may ONLY modify
  // the part of the print statement after:  \n",
  // fprintf(stdout, "Found %d approximate matches.\n", count);



  //finally, print out the end time and date. Right now only printing
  //a default string. 
  time(&end); // read and record clock
  local = localtime(&end);
  printf("\n# End time and date: %s", asctime(local));

  exit(0);
}
```

utils.c

```
#include "utils.h"

int approxEqual(double x, double r, double t)
{
    int ceiling = r+t;
    int floored = r-t;

    if(x > floored && x < ceiling)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;

}
```

utils.h

```
#if ! defined(UTILS_H)
#define UTILS_H

int approxEqual(double x, double r, double t);

#endif
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great

How i compiled it

```
gcc -c utils.c
gcc findvals.o utils.o -o findvals
gcc -c findvals.c
```

Comment: Which file is each listing?  And shouldn't you compile the individual sources before linking them together?

Comment: edited compiling them like that worked before :(

Comment: Do gcc -c findvals.c before you do gcc findvals.o utils.o -o findvals

Comment: Better still write yourself a makefile.

Comment: Still not working even though i did them in the correct order. Googling makefile now

Comment: Works all ok for me on debian wheezy. Check if your utils.o is being built.

Comment: this code will fail if the command line is written with no space between the -t or -r and the value.  also, the -t and -r need to be passed through 'tolower()' so the comparisons always work. (or output an error message if -T or -R are entered

Comment: it is best to NOT cast the return pointer from malloc()

Comment: the code malloc's several memory areas.  Those same memory areas need to be passed to free() before exiting the program, to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: your original compile sequence is using the object file from the prior compile/link/compile sequence.  That is why it 'seems' to work.

Comment: the code needs to check the returned value from each malloc() to assure success.  otherwise using the returned value will result in UB and probably a seg fault event.

Comment: the code needs to check the returned value from each scanf() to assure a value was successfully input/converted.

Comment: the format string parameter for each scanf() should have a ' ' as the first char so any white space (I.E. the newline char) is skipped.  otherwise any white space character will cause the scanf() to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use a makefile such as the one shown below.

```
.PHONY: all clean

SRCS := findvals.c utils.c
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

all: findvals

findvals: $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o findvals
```

Simply save this file in the same directory as your source, call it "makefile" or "Makefile" and use the command

```
make
```

As a side note. In your main function you should add a check incase the user does not provide enough command line arguments. You can tell how many are provided by using the argc variable and you should not reference any argv values higher than *argc - 1* or you will have a crash.

Answer (score 0):

gcc -c utils.c findvals.c utils.h

gcc findvals.o utils.o -o findvals

Check this. This will work.