# Understanding a makefile better - How the .o file gets generated in this case

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I currently have the following makefile (I am using an example of an online tutorial) which works however I have a few questions regarding this:

```
# *****************************************************
# Variables to control Makefile operation

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g


test:  main.o car.o student.o   house.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test main.o car.o student.o house.o
    objcopy --only-keep-debug test test.debug   

main.o: student.h house.h  main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

car.o: car.h

student.o: student.h car.h

house.o: house.h 

clean:
    rm -rf *.o test *.debug
```

Here is my understanding of what is going on here please correct me if I am wrong. When **initially** test target is called it looks for the first dependency `main.o` This could either be a file or a target. Since there is no file called `main.o` it will look for `main.o` as a target. Once main.o as a target is found it looks for  dependencies `student.h house.h main.cpp` since these exist as a file make then executes the recipe (command) which is `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp`. Now here is the part that I dont understand. When the second dependency `car.o` turn comes up make looks for car.h and finds it but there is no command that tells it to generate the .o file. How is the .o file being generated here ?

Comment: Run `make -p` to find out builtin rules. Rule `make --trace` or use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x` to understand what is happening.

Comment: On minor note: you say above _it could either be a file or target_.  That's not how make works: it considers EVERY prerequisite a target.  If make cannot find an applicable rule to update the target, and the target file exists, then make considers the target "built" and keeps going.  That's how files like `car.h` are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in rule for generating an .o file from a .cpp file.

You have told it that is has an extra dependency of car.h, but not how to make car.o so it falls back on the built in rule, with car.h as an added dependency.

You could change

```
main.o: student.h house.h    main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp
```

to

```
main.o: student.h house.h
```

and it would build it too using the built in rule. Its documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit).

You could also use a built in rule to make your test binary, were you not also running the objcopy command.

Instead of

```
test:  main.o car.o student.o   house.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test main.o car.o student.o house.o
```

You could just use

```
test:  main.o car.o student.o   house.o
```

Comment: Is there a reason you linked to a very old version of the make manual?

Comment: so if I used only the dependencies `student.h` and `house.h` in `main.o: student.h house.h` without adding the command ` $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp`  then make would simply add those commands on its own (if they were missing )?

Comment: @MistyD Make has a prebuilt rule that knows how to make an .o from a .cpp file. When it sees it needs to make an .o file it looks for any of the files it can use to meet that requirement. First it looks in your own rules then it looks in the built in rules. It finds a main.cpp and invokes the rule that converts .cpp to .o. If you had a main.c file instead it would invoke the rule to convert a .c file to a .o file.

Comment: Do a google search for o'reilly gnu make. I believe they are giving away their book on gnu make. Its an old book, but make hasn't changed that much over the years. Even the first couple of chapters will give you a massive insight into how it works and improve your understanding of makefiles.

Comment: Be careful when saying "First it looks in your own rules then it looks in the built in rules". Rule choice order is not that simple and changed in make 3.82 (I believe).

Comment: @PaulRooney I tried  using what you suggested `main.o: student.h house.h` instead of my current one and unfortunately it does not work. I get `g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory`. Is there anything that I might be missing ?

Comment: Look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599004/header-file-wont-work-undefined-reference-to-method/26599363#26599363 of a makefile this should be adaptable to your case

Comment: The example in the link does not add header dependencies but you can leave any of the lines that are like `student.o: student.h car.h` and it will take not of modifications to these files when rebuilding.

Comment: @PaulRooney I think I am pretty comfortable with the make concept however I am just curious as to why student object file does not get generated from `student.o: student.h car.h`

Comment: Is student.o a dependency of your binary and do you have a student.cpp? It's hard to tell without seeing your full makefile.

Comment: Ill add all of my makefile to the post

Comment: If you type make student.o what happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63984/discussion-between-mistyd-and-paul-rooney).

Answer (score 2):

make contains several implicit rules. That means that make has built-in knowledge about how to create a .o file from a .cpp file without you telling it explicitly how to do that.

From the documentation:

> Compiling C++ programs
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or
>   n.C with a recipe of the form ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’. We
>   encourage you to use the suffix ‘.cc’ for C++ source files instead of
>   ‘.C’

You may think of this as make having a built-in rule that looks quite like:

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Read more about these implicit rules [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

Most `make` (and similar) programs pre-define implicit rules for things like converting a source file (with any of a number of common extensions) to object file (using their default extension).

Typically that'll be equivalent to something like this:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $*.o -c $*.c

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $*.o -c $*.cc
```

...with more for other common extensions, so it'll not only know how to compile most typical extensions (.c, .cc, .cpp, .C, etc.) to .o files, but also implicitly pick up the content of some variable you can specify as the set of flags to pass to the compiler when it does so.

As for the details of these rules: a rule like `.cc.o:` is an implicit rule--it basically says "if you have a .cc file you can create a .o file from it using this rule". These get used as kind of a backstop--if you have an explicit rule telling how to create some specific .o file, `make` will use that by preference--but if there isn't an explicit rule, it can fall back on the implicit rule instead.

The `$*` is a built-in macro, that expands to the base name (without the extension) of the source file. There are a number of them for just the base name of the source (`$*`) and the full name of the source file (`$<`). There are a number of other automatic variables like this, but from what I've seen most people using them rarely enough that they have to look them up when they need to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation however could you please explain what `.cc.o:` and `$*.o` would mean from the rule

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. I had to go with Pauls answer. Your explanation definitely  helped. Thanks again for expanding your answer too